# Recommended practices for the amount of rows you can have in an Azure Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Is there any guidelines or practices around how much a SQL Database can handle?

If you have a single table with following columns:

Id, int
Update, bit
Status, nvarchar(256)
Path, nvarchar(256)
Category1, nvarchar(256)
Category2, nvarchar(256)

All columsn are indexed.

We will update 10 entries every second. Is there any guidelines when an Azure Database will have decreased performance. We need a storage with 400 million rows and I am worried that Azure SQL Database will be to slow for this scenario (unless you buy some 4K dollars plan). Beside updating the DB, we also need to be able to query for how many rows, that has a specific status, or has been updated. So table storage would fall on this requirement.

Any experience with this kind of scenarios would be helpfull, or some alternatives to SQL Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's a great and very common question, so let's try to give it a complete and hopefully definitive answer.

First thing first: it really doesn't matter if you're storing 400 million rows or 10 million. It all depends what you plan to do with it. If you need to access one, or few row at time, using a search condition that can use an index, you're good to go. Performance will always be pretty fast (milliseconds to get the data - single or double digits depending on the service level you buy - and then, depending on the network bandwidth, other some milliseconds to return the data. If, instead, you plan to SCAN the data; for example, group and count all the rows where Category is equal to something, then you need more raw power as you'll be able to get data as fast as it can be scanned. This is true for SQL and for any other database (relational or NoSQL).

Second important thing to keep in mind. The fact that you have index doesn't mean that they will be used. I won't go in details here but in general an index is useful only if restrict the search space a lot. IF you have 400 million rows, and for 90% of the that rows you set the Category column to "ACME"...well if you search for "ACME" you bet that index won't be used as it would be way too expensive compare to a more naif table (scan). The exception to this are clustered and columnstore index...if you want to start to learn more you can read here: https://medium.com/sql-server-for-the-better-developer

Third point: 10 insert per second are almost nothing. With the exception of some very basic free tier you can easily insert several hundreds of rows per second, as a general baseline.

Last point: you mention that one use case is to "be able to query for how many rows, that has a specific status, or has been updated." If you want to otimize your costs and are will to move a bit of data consistency resposability to the application or middle tier, you can write to your big table the single transaction and create other tables to keep some pre-aggregated data updated and ready to be queries without having to scan the whole table. Sort of "materialized view" approach. IF you can't do that, for example beacuse that pre-aggreated table would be big as the 400M rows table itself, then you *need* a columnstore (this is available in Azure SQL) so that aggreated will be returned really really fast.

Now some question for you: what is the budget you're looking for? What makes you think Azure SQL could be "too slow" for your scenario?

PS
Full disclosure, I'm now a Program Manager in Azure SQL. I joined recently before that I had to deal with something very similar to what you are asking. More info on that experience here: https://medium.com/@mauridb/from-elasticsearch-back-to-sql-server-597249c16a9d

Comment: WOW very helpfull - thanks! It is a big enterprise customer so we get the budget we need. I would say hopefully not over 1.5k USD. But if higher is needed, then that is how it is. We will have around 300 million rows. I added around 20 millions for testing and performance is still acceptable. I would say only problem right now is deleting rows.  I have a category with 700000 k rows. Deleting them took around 1.5 hour. I did another thread on that subject where batch delete was recommended but same performance. I understand that is expected, that deletes just are slow.

Comment: 1.5k USD per month I guess? You can get really good performances for that amount of money. Remember also that if you don't need the same performance across the 24h, you can scale up and down to save more. For what concerns the deletes. If you need to delete that amount of rows the best option is to partition data per category and then drop the partition when you need to delete all its rows.